# On a Marley baseboard electric heater 2500 does it matter what wire connects to what wire of a dial thermostat?

Tags: wire, heat

An electrician friend of mine told me to get a Marley 2500 heater, and I was wondering if there's any specific order to connect wires to outside of no crossing color paths outside of the heater itself?

The manual can be found here: http://www.marleymep.com/en/assets/pdf/5200-2194-010.pdf

We're wiring the left side with a switch.

Comment: Try reading the brochure or installation stuff.

Comment: My dad, and I who are both software engineers have tried.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. I have answered what I think you are asking, let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: This belongs in Home Improvement. To the OP, please post links to model of thermostat and heater if possible. Pictures could also help.

Comment: You're wiring this to a North American 240V/1ph circuit, right?

Comment: Yes, in MN I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your thermostat control is double-pole, then it doesn't really matter which switched wire gets connected to which heater wire.  But if the thermostat is single-pole, then as HighInBC says, make sure it switches the hot wire.

With the single-pole, looking at figure 5 in the referenced manual, connect the switched hot to field wiring point L2, ie. the safety limit switch.  Connect your neutral to field wiring point L1, ie. the heater element.

That way, when the heater eventually stops working because the thermostat has failed or the safety limit switch has opened, and you or your dad stabs the element with a screwdriver, you probably won't die.

Comment: How do I know one of you will touch the element with a screwdriver?  I have worked with software engineers all my life and I have never met one (yes, including me) who could refrain from doing this.

Comment: We didn't realize at first the circuit needs to be connected at both ends, so the wires can be exposed together.  After that it worked just fine in the continuous loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a Marley 2500 heater is but I am assuming it has a switch on it. There is a correct way. When wired correctly the switch will interrupt the hot wire, if wired backwards it will interrupt the neutral wire.

In base cases it will work, however if wired backwards then parts of the device will be hot when they are not supposed to be.

A classic example is a toaster. If wired correctly touching the elements should not shock you when the plunger is up. However if it is wired backwards the elements will be hot and if you are grounded you can get shocked.

Comment: FYI - in countries with decent regulatory requirements :-) - and anywhere sensible, toasters should have break switches in BOTH leda. All NZ ones do and I caused a productrecall after a nephew got a 230V shock because one break contact as trapped on in assembly in about 10% of the toasters.